# Split gcc output by thread/job

Tags: gcc, g++, gcc-warning, buildbot

I want to do statistics on compiler warnings per compilation unit based on the compiler output of gcc/g++. This is no problem with `-j1` but with multiple threads, e.g. `-j4`, the output is completely mixed. Can I either

- get the compiler to write the output per compiler thread to different files/outputs or
- "atomically" print all output/warnings for a single compilation unit together?

I'm using gcc/g++ **8.1** and (if this helps) buildbot.

Comment: If you use **Jenkins**, a plugin called `scan for compiler warnings` will help you do this kind of statistics.

Comment: I'm using buildbot - and unfortunately, I haven't yet found a comparable feature there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent enough versions of GNU make have an option, `-O`, which controls the behavior of parallel output:

- [Output During Parallel Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html)

It is a good idea to specify `-O` each time you request a parallel build with a `-j` option.